# BCM4360 5Ghz AP-mode on Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, wireless-access-point

I want to setup an access point on Linux on the 5Ghz band.
However the current card I have doesn't support this (the Intel Wireless-AC 7260), so I want to buy another one. I thought of an Asus PCE-AC68, apparently using a broadcom BCM4360 chip. This chip doesn't seem to be supported by the b43 and the brcmfmac drivers.

Will it support AP mode on 5Ghz with the broadcom-wl driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same Asus PCE-AC68 card and unfortunately it does not support AP mode on Linux x86 platform. As the AP part of the driver is closed source and is available for ARM only as a binary object file.

Maybe, sometime someone will develop it. :(

Comment: Thanks, have you heard of any other another PCIe card supporting AP mode on 5Ghz ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.
But I can advise you to search something without Broadcom chip :). Realtek or Atheros as an example.

Comment: I bought a card with a Realtek RTL8812AE chip. Indeed it works as an AP in the 5Ghz band. However I can't get 802.11n/ac to work. When 802.11n is enabled on hostapd, the client doesn't receive any packets, and enabling 802.11ac doesn't change anything. Only 802.11a works apparently.

Comment: Check that hostapd is a latest version, compiled options, driver version, etc...

Comment: I'm on ArchLinux so I think it is.

Comment: Just found out that deleting rtl8812aefw.bin firmware makes 802.11n work. Sadly, still no luck with 802.11ac, can't figure what's wrong.

Comment: What is your card model? May be I'll purchase the same one to play with it. :)

Comment: Sparklan WPET-232ACN

Comment: Seems with recent updates that 802.11ac works finally. However it's not very stable and I get 60Mb/s average when connected to the RTL8812AE access point  while I have 230Mb/s average when connected to a TP-Link Archer C5 AC1200. (client is an Intel Wireless AC 7260)

Comment: Recently bought an USB 3.0 dongle with RTL8812AU chip inside, will try to play with it later.

Comment: Any updates on a working and stable 5Ghz AP-mode chipset on Linux in 2018?

Comment: @MountainX which chipset are you asking about?

Comment: @RealQuaker Actually, I'll use any chipset you recommend which has a good Linux driver with AP mode support and supports 5Ghz 802.11ac. I am looking for a PCI-e card. USB adapter would be 2nd choice. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: @MountainX Currently I can recommend Atheros based only cards which have a mainline Linux Kernel drivers with both AP and Client Mode. I bought recently Atheros based Mikrotik  [R11e-5HacT](https://mikrotik.com/product/R11e-5HacT) 5Ghz miniPCI-e, 802.11ac/a/n tripple chain card. There is also cheaper dual chain card available [R11e-5HacD](https://mikrotik.com/product/R11e-5HacD). These are are the only ones cards I found with Atheros chips.

Comment: @RealQuaker - thank you. I will try the Mikrotik R11e-5HacT.

Comment: @MountainX Please note that these cards have specific antenna connectors(MMCX). Consider to order MMCX to RPSMA pigtails or MMCX connector antennas and miniPCI-E to PCI-E adapter. Welcome!

Comment: 8 years on in 2023, and the BCM4360 is still only supported by a proprietary driver from 2015 that I can't make work in AP mode for the life of me. This chip is common in Apple hardware from that 2013-2016 vintage.

Comment: Broadcom joined NVidia https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ